# MultiLingual In Single Page - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, multilingual, rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Is it possible to achieve using more than one language on loading a single page using I18n in Rails 5. Say for eg: I have a Q&A page where the question can be displayed in 'English' below which another regional language as translation for user to understand. Means simultaneously displaying two langual. Is it achievable? what would be way to do the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`rails-i18n` provides a method [`with-locale`](https://translation.io/blog/rails-i18n-with-locale) to override the globally set locale for a particular block of code. e.g. if you have set global `I18n.locale` to, say 'Japanese' for a particular request:

```
# application_controller.rb
I18n.locale = :ja
```

but you want to show some of the content in your view, using a different locale, as you say, 'English', you can do it as follows:

```
<!-- my_view.html.erb -->

<% I18n.with_locale(:en) do %>
  <%= t_question %>      <!-- assuming `t_question` is a method, which returns the localised text (in this case, in english) for question in your application -->
<% end %>

<%= t_answer %>          <!-- this should render the answer in japanese -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the similar page it's not possible but for different page it's possible.

The effective way of setting the language is to add it as prefix to the URL. This enables search engines to manage different language versions better. Suppose if we want localhost:3000/de to display the German version of our homepage and localhost:3000/en the English version. We need to write in config/routes.rb

```
myapp::Application.routes.draw do
 scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|de/ do
  root :to => 'page#index'
  get "page/index"
 end
end
```

Next, we need to set a before_filter in the app/controllers/application_controller.rb. This filter sets the parameter locale set by the route as I18n.locale:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery
before_filter :set_locale

private
 def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
 end
end
```

Comment: I think, she is doing this stuff already i.e. displaying whole page in a single locale.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, Yes you are right. Saw your reply. It helped

Comment: @Radhika did you check my answer? It does exactly that. You can display sections of your template in different languages using `with_locale` as metioned in my answer.